# Publish Code Coverage result Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to publish the code coverage result for .NET framework 4.6.1 in Azure DevOps. I am using visual studio test task to run unit test cases and get the code coverage. After successful execution of Visual studio test task, I am getting a code coverage result in a '.coverage file'.I have opened the coverage file in visual studio in my laptop and verified it shows the number of line covered and not covered in unit test.

Using vstest.console.exe I am converting the coverage file to xml and using report generator to publish the code coverage result.

[image: Run codecoverage.exe]
[image: ReportGenerator Task settings]

After successfully completed the above steps, when i click code coverage tab i am presented with html link to download the coverage file. I want to publish the coverage file in the code coverage tab itself.

[image: Empty Code Coverage page]

I have also tried this as well [other similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54627918/view-code-coverage-report-on-azure-devops-portal), when i try, i am getting a coverage.cobertura.xml with 1kb doesn't have any details about code covered in unit test.

```
&dotnet tool install dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool --tool-path . --version 4.0.12
&dotnet tool install coverlet.console --tool-path . --version 1.4.1

"`nmake reports dir:"
mkdir .\reports

"`nrun tests:"
$unitTestFile = gci -Recurse | ?{ $_.FullName -like "*bin\*UnitTestProject2.dll" }
Write-Host "`$unitTestFile value: $unitTestFile"

$coverlet = "$pwd\coverlet.exe"

"calling $coverlet for $($unitTestFile.FullName)"
&$coverlet $unitTestFile.FullName --target "dotnet" --targetargs "vstest $($unitTestFile.FullName) --logger:trx" --format "cobertura"

"`ngenerate report(s)"
gci -Recurse | 
    ?{ $_.Name -eq "coverage.cobertura.xml" } | 
    %{ &"$pwd\reportgenerator.exe" "-reports:$($_.FullName)" "-targetdir:reports" "-reporttypes:HTMLInline;HTMLChart" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you add `Publish code coverage` task to the pipeline? Code coverage Tab only supports code coverage data in `Jacoco` or `Cobertura` formats, result of the *.coverage file can not be shown by tables and graphs.

Add "Publish code coverage" task with these parameters:

[image]

Here is some tickets([case1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56524911/11508192),[case2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62394233/azure-devops-builds-not-showing-code-coverage-when-using-dotnet-test-collec)) with similar issue you can refer to.

Comment: When i ran the coverlet command `& $coverlet $unitTestFile.FullName --target "dotnet" --targetargs "vstest $($unitTestFile.FullName) --logger:trx" --format "cobertura"` Unit test is not executing and getting  ```No test is available in E:\test\_work\4\s\CUnitTest\bin\Release\CUnitTest.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66332369/coverlet-not-executing-unit-test-cases I have raised a seperate stackoverflow question for the same as well