# How to Generate Code Coverage Report for both asp.net framework and asp.net core unit tests in Azure DevOps?

Tags: asp.net, azure, unit-testing, asp.net-core, .net-4.8

In project we have both asp.net core and asp.net framework sln. Now I need to get Code  Coverage Report for both asp.net framework and asp.net core unit tests in Azure DevOps.
Please help me out.
I have already checked "[This Article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56516073/how-to-generate-code-coverage-report-for-asp-net-unit-tests-in-azure-devops-buil)" it is not working for me.
I am using Visual Studio Test task for Tests it is working fine and showing the results in Tests tab.
When I enabled **Code coverage enabled** in the VS Test task it is simply publishing .coverage file but not displaying the code coverage report.